# key error in searchtweets API

Tags: python, twitter, keyerror

I am new to `searchtweets` API and am getting a key error while executing the code as follows.

My Code:

```
from searchtweets import collect_results,ResultStream, gen_rule_payload, 
load_credentials
premium_search_args = load_credentials("E:\\residency_5\\practicum\\twitter_keys.yaml",yaml_key="search_tweets_premium",env_overwrite=False)
```

My Yaml file:

```
search_tweets_api:
  account_type: premium
  endpoint: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/30day/dev.json
  consumer_key: wgjwneglwegkweglkew
  consumer_secret: rglknrgkrwrerherhrehreh
```

The error I am getting is:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-a65d7e772e67> in <module>()
----> 1 premium_search_args = load_credentials("E:\\residency_5\\practicum\\twitter_keys.yaml",yaml_key="search_tweets_premium",env_overwrite=False)

C:\Users\Srivatsav\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\searchtweets\credentials.py in load_credentials(filename, account_type, yaml_key, env_overwrite)
    184                    if env_overwrite
    185                    else merge_dicts(env_vars, yaml_vars))
--> 186     parsed_vars = _parse_credentials(merged_vars, account_type=account_type)
    187     return parsed_vars
    188 

C:\Users\Srivatsav\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\searchtweets\credentials.py in _parse_credentials(search_creds, account_type)
     80         """
     81         logger.error(msg)
---> 82         raise KeyError
     83 
     84     try:

KeyError:
```

How can I fix this. Is there something wrong with my yaml file? Thanks in advance

Comment: In your python code you're requesting to load `yaml_key="search_tweets_premium"` but your yaml file contains the key as `search_tweets_api`. Replacing the `yaml_key:"search_tweets_api"` should help

Comment: worked!! thanks bro

Comment: You're welcome. I posted the same in more detail as an answer for this question. Feel free to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you have a `KeyError` is because the key you wanted to find in the `yaml` file doesnot exist with the same name you have mentioned in your python code. You are requesting the `yaml_key="search_tweets_premium"` which means the `yaml` file has a key with the name `search_tweets_premium` but instead this key is not found in the `yaml` file.

The key in your `yaml` file is `search_tweets_api` instead of `search_tweets_premium`. Either correct the key in the `yaml` file or the python code such that they're both the same and your code should work fine.